# Nested foreach to Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am new to LINQ, help me convert this nested line of codes to LINQ.

```
foreach(var rule in rules)
{
    foreach(var package in packages)
    {
        if(rule.KeyFrom == package.Key || rule.KeyTo == package.Key)
        {
            filteredRule.Add(new RuleModel{Package = new List<string>{rule.KeyTo, rule.KeyFrom}, Rule = rule.Rule});
        }
    }
}
```

Attempted query:

```
rules.SelectMany(r => packages.Select(p => p.Key == r.KeyFrom || p.Key == r.KeyTo))
     .Select(new RuleModel {
          Package = new List<string>{ r.Keyfrom, r.KeyTo}, 
          Rule = r.Rule 
     }));
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried. `SelectMany` can help

Comment: I can't see your attempt

Comment: I am not able to write the query that's the issue. @MarcoSalerno

Comment: Aren't you able to try?

Comment: The way SO works is that you show attempts. Even if it is not complete, but still show some effort. We can help correct from there. There are many of Linq examples and previous questions

Comment: Updated the question. @GiladGreen

Comment: And what happened with that attempted query? It would really help if you'd format the code more usefully - the second `Select` belongs under the `SelectMany` rather than under the first `Select`, given that it's called on the *result* of `SelectMany`.

Comment: @siddharth - Good :) just explain what is the problem with the attempt and then it is a good question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Your problem is that in the `SelectMany` you used `Select` for filtering insead of using `Where`:

```
rules.SelectMany(r => packages.Where(p => p.Key == r.KeyFrom || p.Key == r.KeyTo))
      .Select(r => new RuleModel {
          Package = new List<string>{ r.Keyfrom, r.KeyTo}, 
          Rule = r.Rule 
      }));
```

- [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx) - *Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate*
- [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) - *Projects each element of a sequence into a new form*

Comment: The formatting here is very deceptive - it looks like the `Select` is called on the result of `Where`, but it's actually called on the result of `SelectMany`. I strongly recommend that you outdent lines 2-5 so that the `Select` call lines up with `SelectMany`.

Comment: @GiladGreen, 'r' in Select() block is not recognizable. The scope of it is only in SelectMany().
I am getting "The name 'r' is not in current context"  error.

Comment: @siddharth - corrected - forgot to add the `r =>` in the `select`

Comment: then it will be an instance of packages.

Comment: @siddharth - Yes - `SelectMany` returns for each item of rules many items. The `Where` returns `packages` that meet the predicate. So `SelectMany` returns packages

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `SelectMany`.

The code will be like this:

```
var ruleModels = rules.SelectMany(r => r.packages).Where(rule.KeyFrom == package.Key || rule.KeyTo == package.Key).Select(r => new RuleModel{Package = new List<string>{r.KeyTo, r.KeyFrom}, Rule = r.Rule});

filteredRule.AddRange(ruleModels);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the below code:

```
    filteredRule.AddRange(rules.Where(b =>
 packages.Any(a => b.KeyFrom == a.Key || b.KeyTo == a.Key)).select(
p=>new new RuleModel { Package = new List<string> 
{ p.KeyTo, p.KeyFrom }, Rule = p.Rule }));
```